# Replace ESAPI.encoder() with OWASP Encoder Project

Tags: java, owasp, encoder, esapi

In the last year i used ESAPI project to sanitize and bring the html to common form, today i saw that my mainly heavy "traffic" is mainly because of the only line that i use from ESAPI:

```
ESAPI.encoder().canonicalize(string);
```

I read about OWASP new project "Java Encoder" which is a lightweight of the whole ESAPI to whom want to use only the encoder(and i do).
The only thing i'm not quite understood, is how to replace the one line with the new Encoder?(hence, it doesn't have encoder() and canonicalize() functions).
The only way i found is to parse it through is:

```
Encode.forHtml();
Encode.forCssString()
```

and so on.
Is there another way? or maybe i even didn't understood right the documentation.

Comment: yes. don't forget to add the .jar in your pom.xml or orther artifact and pass the string to encode as argument

Comment: yes of course. but isn't there another way to make the canonicalize without passing in to 10 different functions? (if i'm not mistaken, canonicalize does it, he search for a specific format and parse it)

Comment: also, it's not working the same, previously if i passed argument like "%3Cscript%3E" to the canonicalize it would return <script>, i didn't found any function from Encode that would do the same.

Comment: The Owasp encoder project ONLY escapes output.   It does no intrusion detection nor decoding of user input.